# Android - EditText с показом номера линии

Tags: android, android-edittext, java

Приветствую! Уже долгое время я пытаюсь найти кастомный EditText, который показывает номера строк. Например, [такой есть у AIDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N67RW.png). Есть ли какое-нибудь готовое решение? Если нет, то в какую сторону копать, чтобы сделать кастомный EditText?

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если через кастомный `EditText`, то самое простое:

```
public void init() {
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setTextSize(14);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int lineHeight = getLineHeight();
    int lineCount = getLineCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < lineCount; i++) {
        canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(i + 1), 0, i * lineHeight + lineHeight,     mPaint);
    }

    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

[image]